# how to call the directive with different templateurl and conroller from another controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I am completely new to AngularJS. 
 I am having the below HTML code

```
<div id="products" ng-contoller="productController" listProducts></div>
```

This will execute when angular js runs and I am getting all the products in the attribute. My directive is like below

```
learnApp.directive('listproducts',function(){

    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl:"products.php",
        controller:"productController"
    };
});
```

But I am having the shopping cart with selected product ids

so when the cart is clicked, I want to replace the directive with the selected products details.

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart' ng-click='productDetails();'>{{totalProductList.totalProducts}}</span>
```

like below

the `productDetails` function should call the directive and replace it with `productDetails.php`

```
learnApp.directive('listproducts',function(){

    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        if(shoppingCartImageclicked)
        {
        templateUrl:"productDetailsForSelectedItems.php",
        controller:"productDetailControllerForSelectedItems"
        }
        else // initial load
        {
            templateUrl:"productDetails.php",
            controller:"productDetailController"
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: ``the productDetails function should call the directive `` is this part done??

Comment: Edited..When the page lodas I am getting the list of products Sameer...I want to replace the product list with product details those are added in shopping cart.is this what you asked ?

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a very bad idea to be honest. that is not how directives are meant to be used.
one directive should have one task. your directive has two tasks, hence should be two directives.
you will have to define a second directive and solve the change of view programatically (at best with javascript) for example by using a different route, or at least ng-show/ng-if.

Comment: Ok,,then I will call the ajax function, display the result  and then hide all the product page .

Comment: that sound much better and much more angular-way :)